# Estimated SEM vs SEM

Tags: estimation, standard-error

I have read the other questions and answers related to my question but the answers were not very clear.

I understand the process of estimating the mean by taking the mean of the sample (our best guess) and then calculating how confident we are of this mean (using the central limit theorem). However, I don't understand why we can estimate the standard error of the mean using the population variance. Would you please provide me some help or links.

Comment: Some possible issues with your premises: 1. "then calculating how confident we are of this mean (using the central limit theorem)"  -- the central limit theorem is not what tells us how the standard error of a mean works. That's down to [properties of variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties) (*et seq*.). The CLT makes use of those facts, but the facts don't come from the theorem; the CLT tells us about the distribution of the standardized mean (in the limit as n goes to infinity).   ... ctd

Comment: ctd...  2. "I don't understand why we can estimate the standard error of the mean using the population variance" -- it's not an estimate but a calculation (given the assumptions hold); it's only once we replace the population variance by an estimate of it that the standard error of the mean in turn becomes an estimate.